# getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) return messy code

Tags: c++

I am using `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)` to read my config file line by line. But it keep returning messy code and this while loop never ends.

Here is the code piece:

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
size_t max_line = MAX_LINE;
while (-1 != getline((char **)&line, &max_line, file)) {
    cout<<"> "<<line<<endl;
    lines.push_back(string(line));
}
```

And the output:

```
> `7▒▒
> `7▒▒
> `7▒▒
```

I read the man-page and followed it.I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: According to https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline you should either be passing the address of a NULL pointer, or a malloc-allocated buffer. Depending on how long the lines in the file are, and `MAX_LINE`'s size, maybe that's a problem?

Comment: And, if you're using C++, why not use std::ifstream and std::string?

Comment: @PhilM It worked for malloc-allocated buffer, but it is so weird for failing when using local char array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted to use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    list<string> lines;
    string line;
    while (getline(file, lie)) {
        cout << "> " << line << endl;
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use [getline from linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) then it should be something like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt");
    list<string> lines;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;
    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        cout << "> " << line << endl;
        lines.push_back(string(line, nread));
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(stream);
}
```